# Significato di "calligrafia svolazzante"

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Sostiene Pereira*, di Antonio Tabucchi, ho letto:

> Sostiene Pereira che il martedì seguente, quando arrivò in redazione, trovò la portiera che gli consegnò un espresso. Celeste glielo consegnò con aria ironica e gli disse: ho dato le sue istruzioni al postino, ma lui non può ripassare più tardi perché deve fare tutto il quartiere, così l'espresso lo ha lasciato a me. Pereira lo prese, fece un cenno di ringraziamento con la testa e guardò se c'era il mittente. Per fortuna non c'era nessun mittente, dunque Celeste era rimasta a bocca asciutta. Ma riconobbe subito l'inchiostro azzurro di Monteiro Rossi e la sua **calligrafia svolazzante**.

Potreste spiegarmi cosa vuol dire l'espressione "calligrafia svolazzante"? Ho cercato il vocabolo "svolazzare" in parecchi dizionari, ma soltanto il [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/svolazzare)  fa riferimento a questa espressione. Tuttavia, non spiega qual è il suo significato.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Significa che la calligrafia era ricca di svolazzi ovvero di ampi tratti di penna che fanno da  abbellimento e orpello; la definizione è tratta dal dizionario del [Corriere](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/S/svolazzo.shtml):

> Nella scrittura manuale, ampio tratto di penna per abbellire una
>   lettera iniziale o una firma: *scrivere con gli s*.

Alcuni esempi:

http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_sLkKBgvGXp8/TMUyNUkSmwI/AAAAAAAAARc/T8PRFyrGAUA/s1600/calligrafia-1.jpg

http://scriptoriumforoiuliense.it/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/corsivo-inglese-880X400.jpg

Answer (score 3):

Trovi la definizione di calligrafia svolazzante sotto la voce [svolazzare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/svolazzare/) su Treccani:

> Part. pres. svolazzante, anche come agg., soprattutto nel sign. 3:
>   *bandiere svolazzanti al vento; svolazzanti sciarpe di vivaci colori*
>   (Saba); e con riferimento al modo della scrittura: una calligrafia s.;
>   *il soldato tracciò una firma svolazzante* (Cassola).

Lo "[svolazzo](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/S/svolazzo.shtml)" è:

> 3. Nella scrittura manuale, ampio tratto di penna per abbellire una
>      lettera iniziale o una firma: *scrivere con gli s.*

Ecco un esempio di calligrafia svolazzante:

[image]