# Cosa vuol dire "firma fiorita"?

Tags: word-meaning, meaning, adjectives

Nel racconto *Cromo* dal libro *Il sistema periodico*, di Primo Levi, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> La prima scaramuccia si svolse in archivio. I due partner, i due fornicatori dal cui amplesso erano scaturiti i mostri aranciati, erano il cromato e la resina. La resina era fabbricata sul posto: trovai gli atti di nascita di tutti i lotti, e non presentavano nulla di sospetto; l’acidità era varia, ma sempre inferiore a 6, come prescritto. Un lotto trovato con acidità 6,2 era stato doverosamente scartato da un collaudatore dalla **firma fiorita**. In prima istanza, la resina era fuori questione.

Non capisco cosa vuol dire che questo collaudatore era "dalla firma fiorita". Ho letto le diverse accezioni di "fiorito" che si trovano sul *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*, ma non sono sicura su come dovrei interpretare l'espressione tenendo conto di quello che ho trovato.

Si tratterebbe di una firma adornata, abbellita ([accezione 5](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI06/00000024.jpg)) o ricca di ornamenti ([accezione 17](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI06/00000025.jpg))? Oppure l'espressione farebbe riferimento alla firma di una persona distinta, celebre, famosa ([accezione 14](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI06/00000025.jpg)) (potrebbe trattarsi di qualche persona importante o nota nella ditta in cui stava lavorando Levi)?

Comment: Secondo me significa appunto che la firma è abbellita, ricca di ghirigori - vedi https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/9226/significato-di-calligrafia-svolazzante

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dal [*vocabolario Treccani*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fiorito/)

> **fiorito** agg. [...] 2. fig. a. *Stile f.*, elegante e pieno di abbellimenti più o meno artificiosi, nella letteratura o nell’arte.

In questo caso si tratta probabilmente di una firma ricca di abbellimenti, in cui si privilegia l'estetica alla leggibilità.

Answer (score 2):

Esiste lo *[stile fiorito](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/stile-fiorito_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27-Arte-Antica%29/)* nei vasi attici, di cui si possono vedere esempi [qui](https://www.frammentiarte.it/2014/00-11-stile-fiorito-attico/).

Si parla di stile fiorito anche nelle [opere di Klimt](https://restaurars.altervista.org/gustav-klimt-dallo-scintillio-delloro-allo-stile-fiorito/).

Direi che è una firma abbellita da ghirigori che possono richiamare decorazioni floreali. O semplicemente molto decorata, come molti usano. Di solito illeggibile.